# FMod channelcontrol callback

Tags: fmod

I wonder, what is a usage of `commanddata1` and `commanddata2` in FMOD channelcontrol callback when `callbacktype == FMOD_CHANNELCONTROL_CALLBACK_SYNCPOINT`?
I was looking on the internet for any answers on this question, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are looking for can be found [here](http://www.fmod.org/documentation/#content/generated/FMOD_CHANNELCONTROL_CALLBACK.html), but to summarize quickly:

- **commanddata1:** (cast to int) The index of the sync point. Use Sound::getSyncPointInfo to retrieve the sync point's attributes.
- **commanddata2:** Always 0.